# Why does mysql_query need a variable to execute?

Tags: php, mysql, execution

When I use this code, everything works perfectly. But when I remove "$enterLocation = ", the code does not get executed and I dont understand why. Any Ideas?

```
$sql_location = "INSERT INTO location (lat, prov, lon, acc) VALUES ('$jsonLocation[lat]', '$jsonLocation[prov]', '$jsonLocation[lon]', '$jsonLocation[acc]')";
$enterLocation = mysql_query($sql_location) or die("Failure!");
```

PS: I am aware that the preferred way is using mysqli_query or even PDO-stuff, which I might implement later on, but I stumbled across this line and wonder why it does not work as intended.

Comment: mysql_query will still get executed, even if you don't assign the result to anything.

Comment: I'd recommend not using `mysql_query()` and look in to using `mysqli` or the PDO - there's plenty of documentation on php.net

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can simply use it like this

```
mysql_query("INSERT INTO location (lat, prov, lon, acc) VALUES ('$jsonLocation[lat]', '$jsonLocation[prov]', '$jsonLocation[lon]', '$jsonLocation[acc]')") or die("Failure!");
```

you dont need to use variables

and you may want to use pdo 
it will works like this :

```
 $db->query("INSERT INTO location (lat, prov, lon, acc) VALUES ('$jsonLocation[lat]', '$jsonLocation[prov]', '$jsonLocation[lon]', '$jsonLocation[acc]')")
```

its better and faster and easier to do you can find help on learning PDO on 
[PHP Official Site](http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php)